# Proof about the subgroup of injective functions being the subgroup of group of even permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have the following problem:

Let $H$ be the subgroup of $S_n$, where $S_n$ denotes the group of injective functions mapping a set to itself, and the order of $H$ is odd. I need to prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $A_n$ where $A_n$ is an alternating group of degree n.

My idea: If the order of $H$ is odd, then it means that the least common multiple of length of the disjoint cycles that make up $H$ is odd, which implies that there are only cycles of odd length. I think all cycles can be written as a multiple of 2-cycles, thus, I can conclude that $H$ is a subgroup of the group of even permutations?

Am I right? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isnt every permutation in $S_n$ a product of 2 cycles? @knsam

Comment: Any permutation is a *product* of disjoint cycles, but not necessarily a disjoint cycle itself. So it's not clear what you mean by "least common multiple of the disjoint cycles that make up $H$". Maybe $H$ doesn't even have any disjoint cycles, but only more "complicated" permutations? And what do the lengths of these cycles anyway have to do with the *order* of H, that is, number of permutations in it? That doesn't seem like the way to go.

Comment: @Avva I meant to write the length of the disjoint cycles that make up $H$. I will fix it there

Comment: @Avva I do not know what you mean by saying that the length of the disjoint cycles have nothing to do with the order of H. The definition in the book indicates that

Comment: The order of $H$ is the number of permutations in $H$. Just make sure you're clear on that. In the *very simple* case when $H$ is generated by just one disjoint cycle, *then* the order of $H$ will be odd if the cycle is odd and even if the cycle is even. But in general $H$ may be much more complicated than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In $S_n$, every permutation is either even or odd, right? And the order (the size) of $A_n$ is exactly half the size of $S_n$. You should already know why this is true.

Now look at even and odd permutations *inside $H$*, that is, consider $H\cap A_n$ which is a subgroup of $H$. You want to prove that it is in fact all of $H$. What if it's not? Then $H$ has both even and odd permutations. By analogy with all of $S_n$, can you try to prove that in that case inside $H$ the number of even and odd permutations is the same? If you prove that, do you see then how this establishes the contradiction you need?

Comment: Would the sketch of the proff be something like this then? If $H$ is not contained in $A$, then it can be written as the product of disjoint cycles, and since $H$ is contained in $S_n$, then some of these disjoint cycles would be even and others odd. Then the least common multiple of lengths of the cycles be even, thus the order of permutations would be even, contradicting that $|H|$ is odd?

Comment: I do not know what happens when $H$ is generated only by one disjoint cycle of odd length tho; then it will still be contained in $S_n$. I think I am yet confused

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say "$H$ can be written as the product of disjoint cycles". One permutation can be written as the product of disjoint cycles. $H$ is not one permutation, it's a subgroup, so it contains many permutations.

Comment: I am yet terribly confused @Avva .Can you elaborate a little bit how can I prove that the number of odd and even permutations within $H$ is the same? I also cannot follow how it can lead to a contradiction. Like, if they are the same, then the multiple of odd and even permutations give even permutations and thus $|H|$ is even?

Comment: Every permutation in $H$ is either odd or even, there're no other options. If the number of odd permutations is the same as the number of even, then together their total number is *an even number*. But we're given that the order of $H$, which is exactly the total number of permutations in $H$, is odd.

Comment: Yes, that was what I was saying. Thanks. But how do we know that the number of odd permutations are the same with those of even permutations? It can be that $H$ can only have odd permutations. No? @Avva

Comment: Let's call $H_{even}$ the subgroup of *even* permutations within $H$ (there's at least one - the identity). And suppose that there is some *odd* permutation $a$ within $H$. Consider two sets $H_{even}$ and $a*H_{even}$ - the second set is all the products of $a$ with even permutations in $H$. These two sets are of the same size. Do you see why the second set contains *only* odd permutations? Can you prove that *any* odd permutation in $H$ must appear in the second set? If you can, then this proves that the number of odd and even permutations in $H$ is the same, right?

Comment: how do we know that $aH_{even}$ is the same size with $H_{even}$ tho?

Comment: sorry if I sound clingy. I just want to get a sense of it. I appreciate your time

Comment: If $H_{even}$ has say 100 members, then $aH_{even}$ is 100 products of $a$ with the $100$ different members of $H_{even}$. Could any of these 100 products be equal to each other? No, because if $a*h_1 = a*h_2$, you can cancel $a$ (by multiplying with $a^{-1}$ on the left) and get $h_1=h_2$. So in $aH_{even}$ all the $100$ products are distinct.

This is a very important point to understand about groups in general: common factors can be canceled. In any group (not just permutations), if $H$ is a subgroup and $a$ any element, $H$ and $aH$ have the same size.

Comment: Don't worry about it. I'm off for the night though. Good luck! Feel free to ask more questions, but I'll only be able to answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

Since $A_n$ is a normal subgroup of $S_n$, we have that $HA_n$ is a subgroup of $S_n$; in case $H\not\subseteq A_n$, this subgroup is the whole of $S_n$, because $A_n$ is maximal, and so
$$
S_n/A_n=(HA_n)/A_n\cong H/(H\cap A_n)
$$
by the homomorphisms theorems.

But $|S_n/A_n|=2$, contradiction.

---

You're confusing things: a permutation can be written as a product of disjoint cycles, but you can't speak about “the disjoint cycles that make up $H$”.

Comment: But surely any permutation in $S_n$ can be written as a product of disjoint cycles, including those in $H$. True these cycles may not lie in $H$, but that fact does not change how we determine the order of $h \in H$.

Comment: Oh? Which odd permutations have order 3?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen in your course (or maybe an earlier one) that if $AB$ are subgroups of a finite group $G$, then the set $AB$ (which need not be a subgroup in general) has cardinality $\frac{|A||B|}{|A \cap B|}$. If you already know that $[S_{n}:A_{n}] = 2$, you can then check that when $H$ is a subgroup of $S_{n}$ of odd order, the set $HA_{n}$ has cardinality $[H :H \cap A_{n}]|A_{n}|$, which is an odd integer multiple of $|A_{n}|$. Since $|S_{n}| = 2|A_{n}|$, we can only have $|HA_{n}| = |A_{n}|,$ so that $H \subseteq A_{n}$.

Alternatively, you can proceed along the lines you were thinking: any $k$-cycle in $S_{n}$ may be written as a product of $k-1$ $2$-cycles. Hence when $k$ is odd, any $k$-cycle is a even permutation, and lies in $A_{n}$. If $H$ has odd order, as you came close to saying, it is the case that every element $h \in H$ can be written as  a product of disjoint cycles, all of odd length, and every such $h$ lies in $A_{n}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am confused about the last sentence of your answer. Like, if $H$ can be written as a product of odd length disjoint cycles, then how can it imply that every $h \in H$ lies within $A_n$. Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: A $2$-cycle is an odd permutation. If $k$ is odd, a $k$-cycle is a product of $k-1$ (not necesarily disjoint) $2$-cycles, and $k-1$ is even, so such a $k$-cycle is an even permutation. Any product  of cycles, all of odd length, is therefore a product of even permutations, so is an even permutation.

Comment: Thank you for acknowledging what I was getting at in earlier comments. The original poster's idea was on track-she just garbled the details. Groups of odd order must contain only elements of odd order, since the order of an element divides the order of the group (Lagrange), and no even number can divide an odd one. And permutations of odd order must be made up of disjoint cycles of odd order, and even permutations are closed under multiplication.